# VS community 2017 confused?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Simple question but really irratating one. Why is Visual Studio community 2017 marking my global declaration of most of my bools green when I do use them ? I MIGHT BE MISSING OUT ON SOMETHING :/ ! I tried uninstall and reinstalling. Didn't work.

```
bool bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingRight = true;
bool bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingLeft = false; // This one is marked in green
bool bMainCharacterYUKONWalkUp = false; // This one is marked in green
bool bMainCharacterYUKONWalkDown = false; // This one is marked in green
bool bMainCharacterYUKONWalkLeft = false; // This one is marked in green
bool bMainCharacterYUKONWalkRight = false; // This one is marked in green
```

[...]

I used those bools on animating functions down here :

```
        private void AnimatingMainCharacterYUKONWalkDown()
        {
            switch (iFrameCounter)
            {
                case 1:
                    pbMainCharacterYUKON.Image = Properties.Resources.Walk__1_;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pbMainCharacterYUKON.Image = Properties.Resources.Walk__2_;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pbMainCharacterYUKON.Image = Properties.Resources.Walk__3_;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pbMainCharacterYUKON.Image = Properties.Resources.Walk__4_;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pbMainCharacterYUKON.Image = Properties.Resources.Walk__5_;
                    break;
            }

iFrameCounter++;

pbMainCharacterYUKON.Top = pbMainCharacterYUKON.Top + 12;

    if (iFrameCounter > 5)
    {
        bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingRight = true;
        bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingLeft = false;
        bMainCharacterYUKONWalkUp = false;
        bMainCharacterYUKONWalkDown = false;
        bMainCharacterYUKONWalkRight = false;
        bMainCharacterYUKONWalkLeft = false;
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: While you write those bool values, you never read them in the code you have shown. The Compiler should be telling you as much.

Comment: The compiler is helping you here - he is telling you that you never used the value of those fields.

Comment: Hold the mouse over those colors or wavy lines and the compiler will *tell you*  what the problem is

Answer (score 2):

Those variables are not underlined because you didn't "use" them--they're underlined because you never read them. Your code demonstrates declaring the bools, then later setting their values, but it never demonstrates you reading their values.

Comment: +dynamicheal I understand the difference but what is reading it then ?It never did that before.

Comment: @Tech Reading it is doing something with the value--displaying it, using it for flow control, using it in some other formula.

Comment: Alright thank you very much everyone ! :D I'll test it out and see!

Comment: It's possible you turned off that warning and then a) forgot you did it, and b) it was somehow reset to its default. Or did you upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio but didn't import your old settings?

Comment: Possible but I don't think so since it doesn't do it anymore but I'm trying to understand how when it is ''used'' ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to dynamichael's answer ....

An example of "reading" a variable is to have it appear on the right side of an equals sign (i.e., on the right side of an assignment statement), e.g.,

```
bool newBool = bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingLeft;
```

or, use it in an expression, e.g.,

```
if (bMainCharacterYUKONIdleFacingLeft == true)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Both of these involve the variable being "read"

Comment: So when would it be ''used'' ?

Comment: Is that ''used'' ? :                                                                                        else if (bMainCharacterYUKONWalkRight == true)
            {
                WalkRight();
            }

Comment: Perhaps "used" isn't the appropriate term. The IDE is warning you that the variable has no practical purpose. If all you do is set the variable but never get its value, then it has no purpose.

Comment: Yes, agreed, "get" is the word. The green squiggles appear when the IDE detects that a variable is defined in a program but then the program never "gets" the contents of the variable.